# how to use imageMagic append 100+ images

Tags: imagemagick, append

I am trying combine 100+ images to one
But I cannot select 100 images in this way `image_[0-100].jpg`
this only work for `image_[0-9].jpg`
any ideas?

also when i am using (convert +append) to combine images this a lot, it is really slow when I run it.
any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your images starting with 000 instead of 0 so they will be appended in proper order.

If you have already named your images with the 0-100 pattern, you can process them with

```
convert image_?.jpg image_??.jpg image_???.jpg +append output.jpg
```

This reads the images with 1-digit numbers first, then the 2-digit ones, and finally the 3-digit ones.

If you created your image sequence with ImageMagick, in the future you can use output filename "image_%03d.jpg"; the "0" means to insert leading zeroes. If you will be creating more than 999 images, use "image_%04d.jpg" instead, to get 4-digit numbers embedded in your filenames (i.e., image_[0000-9999].jpg).

If you are combining a large number of large images and find yourself running out of resources, you can save half the memory and some CPU time by using a Q8 build of ImageMagick.  JPEG images are 8-bit anyway so you won't lose image quality.

Comment: C:\Users\YuboM>convert 8EQE-w8s5FEAAAQIt7h4bg_q6_x-0y-[00-12].jpg +append asasds.jpg
convert.exe: unable to open image `8EQE-w8s5FEAAAQIt7h4bg_q6_x-0y-[00-12].jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.

Comment: try convert 8EQE-w8s5FEAAAQIt7h4bg_q6_x-0y-??.jpg +append asasds.jpg

Comment: thanks for the help bro! just one more question please. I have got 300 images to stitch, when i run this code, my computer looks like crashed. also cpu usage 100%, is there better way for doing it?

Comment: Try a Q8 build to save resources, if you are working with a lot of large images.

Comment: what is Q8 build T.T

Comment: You could join in sections. So join 1-100, then 101-200, then 201-299. And finally join those three parts together. You could try vips as well, but that won't be much quicker for a long horizontal strip.